# How to set and align bullets in a table?

Tags: tables, lists, itemize

I have the following table, the problem with this table is that the bullets are misaligned respect to the text on the right side of the table (second column). How can I align the elements of the second column respect the bullets on the left side:

[image: bullets and content misaligned:]

This is the code what I am using:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\cenMultlCell: \newcommand{\cenMultlCell}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\begin{document}



\begin{table}
    \footnotesize\centering % needed, as table is to wide
    \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=2.2]SS} % supposing that you want to put numbers in the emty cells
        \toprule
        Caracteristica & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Maquina de soporte vectorial} \\\cmidrule(l){2-4}
        Bigrama & {RBF} & {polinomial} & {Lineal} \\\midrule
        Sustantivo/adjetivo 
        & {\cenMultlCell{another fancy text:\\ another text:\\ another text:\\ another one text:\\ another one text:\\ another text:\\ some text:\\ F-Beta another text:}} 
        & {\cenMultlCell{Exactitud:\\ another text:\\ another text:\\ another one text:\\ another one text:\\ another text:\\ some text:\\ another one text:}}
        & {\cenMultlCell{Exactitud:\\ another text:\\ another text:\\ another one text:\\ another one text:\\ another text:\\ some text:\\ F-Beta another text:}} 
\\\midrule
        some text\\
        sdfsfdsf\\
        sdfsdfdfd}\\
        &{\cenMultlCell{another fancy text:\\ another text:\\ another text:\\ another one text:\\ another one text:\\ another text:\\ some text:\\ F-Beta another text:}}
\\\midrule
        & 0.01 & & \\
        Gnu & 92.50 & & \\
        Emu & 33.33 & & \\
        Armadillo & 8.99 & & \\\midrule
        Total: & & & \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{your caption}\label{tab:label}
\end{table}

A reference to \autoref{tab:label}.
\end{document}
```

Any idea of how to fix this identation bullet issue?, I would like to align the bullets with the other content of the table (i.e. the right side). Thanks in advance guys.

I would like to each cell looks algin. So the expected output should look like:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
                         another fancy text:
                         another text:
· alksjdkasldasdas       another one text:
· asdasdas               another one text:
                         another text:
                         some text:
                         F-beta another text:
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Why does the image not match the code? What kind of alignment do you want to achieve?

Comment: @ml_guy, your edits are a bit confusing. Are you asking the question or is @skwoi? Likewise, the image doesn't match the code. (As such, I'm reluctant to accept the edit.)

Comment: @ml_guy Do you have 2 accounts?

Comment: I have two computers... one is linked to one computer and the other is linked to this... @cfr

Comment: You can have the accounts merged by following the instructions at http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts Accounts here are of course not linked to specific computers.

Comment: yes it is... the browser is linked to this computer.@TorbjørnT. Thanks by the way for the remark

Comment: But you can log into the same account in different browsers/computers, so just because you log on from a different computer doesn't mean you have to create a new account. I'm still not sure I quite understand your problem though, does `\cenMultlCell[t]{stuff}` fix it? I.e. add the optional argument `[t]`.

Comment: You table looks fine if you: 1. Use `l` alignment in `\cenMultlCell`: `\newcommand{\cenMultlCell}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}}` and 2. Add a space following the bullet: `\textbullet~`.  If that isn't what you want please post the desired output (and an image that matches the provided MWE).

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks for the help, guys. Still can't solve the issue, I would like to put at the same level of the bullets this part of the table: `        & {\cenMultlCell{another fancy text:\\ another text:\\ another text:\\ another one text:\\ another one text:\\ another text:\\ some text:\\ F-Beta another text:}}`

Comment: By the other hand I tried all the aproaches mentioned here.

Comment: @ml_guy: PLEASE edit the question and provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem, and provide an image of what the desired output is.

Comment: I edited @PeterGrill thanks for the comment.

Comment: @skwoi: The code as posted does not compile -- please make sure you can run it. Also, where are your bullets?

Answer (score 2):

If you replace the lines

```
    some text\\
    sdfsfdsf\\
    sdfsdfdfd}\\
```

with (assuming you want the `\textbullet` in these lines as per your ascii image)

```
\cenMultlCell{\textbullet~some text \\ \textbullet~sdfsfdsf \\ \textbullet~sdfsdfdfd\\}
```

you get:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand{\cenMultlCell}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\begin{document}



\begin{table}
    \footnotesize\centering % needed, as table is to wide
    \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=2.2]SS} % supposing that you want to put numbers in the emty cells
        \toprule
        Caracteristica & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Maquina de soporte vectorial} \\\cmidrule(l){2-4}
        Bigrama & {RBF} & {polinomial} & {Lineal} \\\midrule
        Sustantivo/adjetivo 
        & {\cenMultlCell{another fancy text:\\ another text:\\ another text:\\ another one text:\\ another one text:\\ another text:\\ some text:\\ F-Beta another text:}} 
        & {\cenMultlCell{Exactitud:\\ another text:\\ another text:\\ another one text:\\ another one text:\\ another text:\\ some text:\\ another one text:}}
        & {\cenMultlCell{Exactitud:\\ another text:\\ another text:\\ another one text:\\ another one text:\\ another text:\\ some text:\\ F-Beta another text:}} 
\\\midrule
        \cenMultlCell{\textbullet~some text \\ \textbullet~sdfsfdsf \\ \textbullet~sdfsdfdfd\\}
        &{\cenMultlCell{another fancy text:\\ another text:\\ another text:\\ another one text:\\ another one text:\\ another text:\\ some text:\\ F-Beta another text:}}
\\\midrule
        & 0.01 & & \\
        Gnu & 92.50 & & \\
        Emu & 33.33 & & \\
        Armadillo & 8.99 & & \\\midrule
        Total: & & & \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{your caption}\label{tab:label}
\end{table}

A reference to \autoref{tab:label}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ml_guy: If the solution worked for you please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) and perhaps [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).